# Compare rows in same 2d array in java using deepEquals method

Tags: java, arrays

user input n number of rows in 2d array
Elements are stored in an array of size [n][4].
Input Format:
First line of the input is an integer “n” that denotes the number of rows.
Next n lines contain the elements of the row

Output Format:
if 2 rows match then separate it by hyphen
If no rows is same, print "None".
If the array size is negative, print "Invalid Input" and terminate the program.

Sample Input 1:

```
5
3 1 2 4
2 4 5 1
3 1 2 4
2 4 5 1
3 1 2 4
```

Sample Output 1:

```
1-3
1-5
2-4
3-5
```

Sample Input 2:

```
3
3 1 2 4
2 4 5 1
3 4 2 5
```

Sample Output 2:

```
None
```

Sample Input 3:

```
-5
```

Sample Output 3:

```
Invalid Input
```

i have tried the following code but it didnt work

```
    import java.util.Arrays; 
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*; 

public class Main 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
{ 

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int n = sc.nextInt(); 

    if(n <= 0)
    {
       System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    }
    else
    {
int[][] data = new int[n][4]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        { 
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
                { 
                    data[i][j] = sc.nextInt(); 
                }
        } 
        Object[] array = new Object[4];
        Object[] array1 = new Object[4];
        int idx = 0;
        int idx1 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        { 
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
                { 
                   array[idx] = data[i][j];
                   array1[idx1] = data[i + 1][j];
                   idx++;
                   idx1++;
                    if (Arrays.deepEquals(array, array1))
                        {
                            System.out.println(i + "-" + j);
                        }
                        else
                        System.out.println("None");
                }
            }
        } int[][] data = new int[n][4]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        { 
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
                { 
                    data[i][j] = sc.nextInt(); 
                }
        } 
        Object[] array = new Object[4];
        Object[] array1 = new Object[4];
        int idx = 0;
        int idx1 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        { 
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
                { 
                   array[idx] = data[i][j];
                   array1[idx1] = data[i + 1][j];
                   idx++;
                   idx1++;
                    if (Arrays.deepEquals(array, array1))
                        {
                            System.out.println(i + "-" + j);
                        }
                        else
                        System.out.println("None");
                }
            }
        }}}
```

Comment: What did you see when you ran a debugger and walked through this code?

Comment: i want to get row by row match its giving element by element

Comment: and its mandatory to use 2d array and deepEquals method

Comment: That does not answer Kon's question.

Comment: "*it didnt work*" What didn't work? Which part? What result do you get?

Comment: after creating object of the 2d array and passing it to the deepEquals mathod

Answer (score 0):

you are taking only the 1st elements in array and array1 in each step not the entire row.
what you need to do is you have to take entire 1 row and compare with the other rows more 'for' loops